# Migration from odoo 10 to odoo 12: Element not found in parent view <xpath>

Tags: odoo, odoo-10, odoo-12

I want to migrate a module from odoo 10 to odoo 12 but it shows me this error

```
L'élément '<xpath expr="//div[@t-if='(acquirers or tokens) and website_sale_order.amount_total']/div/ul/t/li[1]/label/span[@t-field='acquirer.image_small']">' ne peut être localisé dans la vue parente

Contexte de l'erreur :
Vue `payment_inherit`
[view_id: 1843, xml_id: n/a, model: n/a, parent_id: 1593]
None" while parsing None:7, near
<data inherit_id="website_sale.payment">
        <xpath expr="//div[@t-if='(acquirers or tokens) and website_sale_order.amount_total']" position="replace">
        </xpath>
        <xpath expr="//div[@t-if='(acquirers or tokens) and website_sale_order.amount_total']/div/ul/t/li[1]/label/span[@t-field='acquirer.image_small']" position="replace">
        </xpath>
    </data>
```

I checked in website_sale.payment and I found that t-field='acquirer.image_small' doesn't exist anymore in view payment in odoo 12.
From addons:

```
<div id="payment_method" class="mt-3" t-if="(acquirers or tokens) and website_sale_order.amount_total">
                                <h3 class="mb24">Pay with </h3>
                                <t t-call="payment.payment_tokens_list">
                                    <t t-set="mode" t-value="'payment'"/>
                                    <t t-set="submit_txt">Pay Now</t>
                                    <t t-set="icon_right" t-value="1"/>
                                    <t t-set="icon_class" t-value="'fa-chevron-right'"/>
                                    <t t-set="submit_class" t-value="'btn btn-primary'"/>
                                    <t t-set="pms" t-value="tokens"/>
                                    <t t-set="form_action" t-value="'/shop/payment/token'"/>
                                    <t t-set="prepare_tx_url" t-value="'/shop/payment/transaction/'"/>
                                    <t t-set="partner_id" t-value="partner"/>

                                    <t t-set="back_button_icon_class" t-value="'fa-chevron-left'"/>
                                    <t t-set="back_button_txt" t-value="'Return to Cart'"/>
                                    <t t-set="back_button_class" t-value="'btn btn-secondary'"/>
                                    <t t-set="back_button_link" t-value="'/shop/cart'"/>
                                </t>
                            </div>
```

How can I solve this problem? should I add t-field='acquirer.image_small in my view or use something else.

Answer (score 0):

I found a little odd that

```
<xpath expr="//div[@t-if='(acquirers or tokens) and website_sale_order.amount_total']" position="replace"></xpath>
```

(which removes the entire DIV) and

```
<xpath expr="//div[@t-if='(acquirers or tokens) and website_sale_order.amount_total']/div/ul/t/li[1]/label/span[@t-field='acquirer.image_small']" position="replace"></xpath>
```

(which removes the acquirer image inside the DIV) exists alongside because the first one should remove the DIV containing the latter. You sure you're not removing the "Pay with" part only?

Try commenting the last xpath section and verify that the outcome is what you expect. You can also comment both xpath and see if is what is expected.